# How to use "multer" module in Node.Js apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I am watching a Node.Js tutorial, but in the following code I can't understand where the `file` and it's `originalname` property/attribute are defined and come from?

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a file from your application, for example with a frontend multipart form, *multer* adds a `file` attribute to the request, with the characteristics of the uploaded file.

> Multer adds (...) a file or files object to the request object. The
>   (...) file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form. [[github doc]](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multer---)

The `originalname` property of `file` contains, as its name suggests, the original name of that file on the user disk.

When you use `diskStorage`, *multer* internally pass the original request and the `file` to `destination` and `filename` function, so you can perform some specific actions with it.